# How to select specific list elements and add them to a csv row with python

Tags: python, list, loops, csv

i got 2 lists with 6 elements and a loop to write rows to a csv file. For example:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
list2 = [a, b, c, d, e, f]

for i in range(0, 6):
    writer.writerow([stuff1, stuff2, list_element1, list_element2])
```

I want to select the first element of list 1 and 2 and add them to the end of the row, after that i want to select the second element of list 1 and 2 and add them to the second row in my csv file […].

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to _add rows_ to an already existing csv file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming list1 and list2 are of same length,using zip(list1,list2) might seem pythonic but it adds to the space complexity and an additional time to generate the tuple as `zip` does not create a  generator rather a tuple. So though the following look `obvious`  and simple it is the optimal also

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
list2 = [a, b, c, d, e, f]

for i in xrange(len(list1)):
    writer.writerow([stuff1, stuff2, list1[i], list2[i])
```

Comment: `zip` is better to use in this case. It's more succinct. Also, consider if the lengths of the lists were to change or became uneven - you'd very likely end up either missing elements or ending up with `IndexError`.

Comment: I do agree that zip looks pythonic, Here zip creates an additional tuple that is not required in this scenario

Comment: @Tagc space and time complexities are high on using zip.Just try the same with list1 and list2 of size 10000000 and check the time and memmory consumptions

Answer (score 2):

There are different of ways, all depends on kind of objects you iterate and runtime considerations. For this simple example anything should be ok but do consider pros and cons of each.

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
list2 = [a, b, c, d, e, f]

# way 1
for l1, l2 in zip(l1, l2):
     writer.writerow([stuff1, stuff2, l1, l2])

from itertools import izip, izip_longest

# way 2: for equal lengths, better if iterable don't support __len__
# for e.g. generators not having len
for i, _ in enumerate(list1):
    print i
    writer.writerow([stuff1, stuff2, list1[i], list2[i])

# way 3: for equal lengths
# using len() would break if iterable don't support it.
for i in range(len(list1)):
    writer.writerow([stuff1, stuff2, list1[i], list2[i]])

# way 4: for equal lengths - better for huge lists
for i in xrange(len(list1)):
    writer.writerow([stuff1, stuff2, list1[i], list2[i]])

# way 5: izip - equal lengths
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
list2 = [7, 8, 9 ,10, 11, 12]
for l1, l2 in izip(list1, list2):
    writer.writerow([stuff1, stuff2, l1, l2])

# way 6: for different lengths
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
list2 = [7, 8, 9 ,10, 11, 12, 13]
for l1, l2 in izip_longest(list1, list2):
    writer.writerow([stuff1, stuff2, l1, l2])

# way 7: for different lengths
for l1, l2 in map(None, list1, list2):
    writer.writerow([stuff1, stuff2, l1, l2])
```